# Can I leave the airport during an Osaka layover?

Tags: luggage, japan, layovers, canadian-citizens

I have a 17-hour layover in Osaka, Japan. Am I able to leave the airport? I'm a Canadian citizen and I'm flying from Toronto to the Philippines.

If I am able to leave the airport, do I have to collect my luggage or will the airport store it, or send it on to my destination?

Comment: The airport will handle your baggage if you've booked tickets together. They will probably not let you access it for security reasons.

Comment: i'm a canadain citizen, and i'm okay with that do i need to collect at all before i leave to for my final destination?

Comment: Usually, you'll be fine as you are a Canadian and have visa waiver. When you check in at YYZ ask them to check your luggage through; but it will usually be fine even if you don't ask so if both flights are on the same carrier.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are free to leave the airport. Simply follow the signs for arrivals / domestic flights, go through passports and customs and exit into Japan. On the immigration form, put "0 days" in the  "expected length of stay" box. You may be asked why your stay is so short---just be honest, you have a long layover and want to go into the city. Nothing unusual about this at all.

Your bag will not be delivered to you in Osaka, it will be stored ready for your onward flight. Exiting the airport does not change what happens to your bag.

When you return to the airport, if you do not have your onward boarding pass yet, go to a check in desk to get it as normal. If you already have your boarding pass, you can proceed directly to exit control and security.